# UITableView not getting populated

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a peculiar problem. I created a normal Objective C class called SampleTable. I then extended UITableView instead of NSObject. Then in the initWithFrame constructor I initialized the table. I also made a NSMutableArray object for the datasource. I also conformed UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource. I have overridden the necessary methods also.

Now I made an object of this class in another class, and added the object as a subview. The tableView is getting drawn according to the CGRectMake() coordinates I gave to the initWithFrame constructor. But it is not getting populated with the data. I don't know what the problem is.

SampleTable.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface SampleTable : UITableView { 

    NSMutableArray *ItemArray; 

 } 

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *ItemArray;

 -(NSMutableArray *) displayItemArray; 

@end
```

SampleTable.m

```
 #import "SampleTable.h"

 @implementation SampleTable

 @synthesize ItemArray;

 -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frm {

     [super initWithFrame:frm];

     self.delegate=self;

     self.dataSource=self;

     [self reloadData];

     return self;

}

 -(NSMutableArray *) displayItemArray { 

    if(ItemArray==nil) { 

       ItemArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];

    }

  return ItemArray;

 }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 { 

     return 1; 

 }

   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 

    return [ItemArray count];

}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 

    UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

   if (cell==nil) {

   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

    [cell autorelease]; 

   } 

   NSString *temp=[self.ItemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

   cell.textLabel.text = temp; 

  return cell; 

}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

   NSLog(@"didselect");

}

 -(void) dealloc { 

     [ItemArray release];

     [super dealloc]; 

 }

  @end
```

Comment: I'll second that. In the long term it is a good idea to put your code into a `UITableViewController` subclass that is also responsible for creating the `UITableView` instance. Business code is NOT a viewable object.

Comment: Actually i am trying to make a dropdown box. so when i click on a button, an object of SamplTable is created and is added to the subview of the button. I have created the button as well as the UITableView dynamically. so i dnt want to use the UITableViewController.

Comment: Right, Jay - I did remove my comment recommending UITableViewController as I somehow suspected something like an embedded UITableView within something bigger. Ralf certainly is right when it comes to most common usages. Still I would strongly discourage creating such custom controls as users might not be used to them.

Comment: yes i know the complications. but i am asked to create the dropdown custom controll regardless of all these problems. can u plz show me some way to do this. I am a bit desperate here.

Comment: Did you try the solution that Ralf has provided? Did it help? What is the value of [self.ItemArray count] within -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section ?

Comment: hi. yeah i did what ralf said. and its returning null. may b thats the problem. so wat do u thnk i should do.

Comment: Ow, I just realized you never called displayItemArray within the code you have provided!

Comment: hey thnx. i realsied it too. such a stupid mistake. thnx a lot for the help..

Comment: My pleasure - it often helps to have an extra pair of eyes looking at stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did never initialize the ItemArray within your code snippet. Remove the displayItemData method and change the initializer towards:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frm 
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frm])) != nil)
    {
        self.delegate=self;
        self.dataSource=self;
        ItemArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];
        [self reloadData];
    }
    return self;
}
```

You could also simply call that displayItemArray method within the initializer. I feel that method makes no sense as it stands and hence my recommendation to remove it altogether.

Without trying it myself, I am still pretty confident that you can also get rid of that [self reloadData] within the initializer.

Answer (score 1):

During the `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frm` method your code calls `-reloadData` on the `UITableView`. At this point in time your `ItemArray` is not available.

Therefore, when `UITableView` calls it's delegates `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods to get information on what to display in the view, they return one section with zero rows.

*Nothing displayed!*

It might be a (one) solution to change your initialization of the `ItemArray`:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) displayItemArray {
    if(ItemArray==nil) { 
        ItemArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];
        [self reloadData];
    }
    return ItemArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

print value of

```
[self.ItemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

in NSLog... check wether it prints valid value or not....It seems that array's object releasing somewhere before it..

Comment: also print the value of [self.ItemArray count] within (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section